# Как интегрировать OpenGL с элементами управления GUI?

Tags: c++, gui, opengl, поиск-библиотек

Я использую OpenGL и библиотеку freeglut. Необходимо добавить элементы управления на окно (кнопки, чекбоксы и тп). Freeglut не имеет элементов gui, поэтому я предполагаю, что мне необходимо либо написать оконную программу с gui элементами и туда интегрировать изображение OpenGL, либо как-то давать элементы gui во freeglut (знаю про glui, но он очень неудобный). Как я могу это сделать (желательно первым способом)?

Comment: Одно слово: [imgui](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui).

Comment: Могу посоветовать библиотеку ImGUI

Comment: Придется реализовать все эти элементы управления самостоятельно.